# Is the Tag in Package.xml redundant?

Tags: ros, c++, catkin, build-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Am learning :::ROS from here:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

but is not 100% clear to me what is this in the package.xml file

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED
> COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs
> genmsg)

I need to do **REQUIRED** and **COMPONENTS**, but hold on, is not a **roscpp**  required too?  what belowns to **REQUIRED** and what to **COMPONENTS** ???

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257769/is-the-tag-in-package.xml-redundant?/) by [LbrRobix](https://answers.ros.org/users/29792/lbrrobix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-24**:
Are you sure that `roscpp` is required? What if I wrote my entire ROS package in Python? Would `roscpp` still be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The REQUIRED refers to the ROS build system catkin mentioned before the REQUIRED. I.e. build shall fail if catkin (For whatever reason is) Not found.

The COMPONENTS refers to the COMPONENTS  (catkin packages, hence ROS packages) that are needed to build your package because your package depends in Them. These package are listed after COMPONENTS.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1